# IText 7 C# Table Header Cell in the same row with content cell

Tags: c#, itext7

I am wondering whether we can put header the same row with other non-header cell?
Suppose row 1 is a header, and i want another non-header in the same row.
Or is it possible to set cell1 as a header and cell2 (the same row with the cell1) as a non header?

What i want to achieve is that when there is a new page,
the header and non-header contents in the same row.

```
using iText.Html2pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Layout.Borders;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using iText.Layout.Properties;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace PDFMe
{
    class Program
    {
        public const String DEST = "C:\\Users\\ibox\\Downloads\\" + 
        "STACK01.pdf";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(DEST);
            file.Directory.Create();
            new Program().CreatePdfMe(DEST);
         }

        
        public virtual void CreatePdfMe(String dest)
        {
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4, false);
            document.SetTopMargin(60f);

            Paragraph header = new Paragraph("MEMORANDUM").SetUnderline()
               .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
               .SetFontSize(15);

            Paragraph newline = new Paragraph(new Text("\n"));

            document.Add(header);
            document.Add(newline);
            String no = "No.:001/2022";
            string perihal = "INTERNAL STACK";

            Table table = new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(new
                    float[] { 20,80})).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            table.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            
            Cell cell = new Cell(1, 1);
         
            // this is a HEADER CELL
            cell.Add(new Paragraph("<b>Solusi,\nCONTINUED</b>"));
            cell.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
            table.AddHeaderCell(cell);

            cell = new Cell(1,2);
            cell.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            cell.SetItalic().Add(new Paragraph("Continued to Next Page"));
            cell.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);
            
            table.AddFooterCell(cell);

            table.SetSkipFirstHeader(true);
            table.SetSkipLastFooter(true);

            string s = @" afsfadsfasfa
                    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui 
                    blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
                    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
                    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
                    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
                    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
                    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
                    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
                    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
                    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
                    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
                    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
                    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
                    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
                    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
                    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
                    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
                    
                    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
                    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
            ";
            cell = new Cell();
            cell.Add(new Paragraph("Solusisssss"));
            cell.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            table.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).AddCell(cell);


            // this is NON-HEADER CELL    
            cell = new Cell();
            cell.Add(new Paragraph(s));
            cell.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            table.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED).AddCell(cell);
            
            document.Add(table);

           
            int n = pdf.GetNumberOfPages();

            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                document.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph(String
                 .Format("Page " + i + "/" + n)),
                 559, 20, i, TextAlignment.RIGHT,
                 VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);

                if (i == 1) continue;
                document.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph(String
                   .Format(no)),
                   20, 806, i, TextAlignment.LEFT,
                   VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);

                document.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph(String
                   .Format(perihal)),
                   320, 806, i, TextAlignment.CENTER,
                   VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);

               
            }

            document.Close();
        }
     

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please attach the code which you have tried so far. What is the difference of header vs non-header in your context?

Comment: Hi Alexey, thanks, i have posted the codes. Can the header cell in one row with the non header cell? When the new page is created, the header cell that contains "<b>Solusi,\nCONTINUED</b>" is not the same row with part of the non header cell content, in my page read "deletctus, ut aut reiciendis"..regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to combine repeatable (header) and non-repeatable cells in one row. This is not possible at the moment.

You can hack around a little bit though by creating a custom `CellRenderer` that would trick the layout engine into believing that the header cell has a very small height and thus almost no space would be occupied for the header cell. You then can still place the cell as usual.

Note that for this trick we need to move the border from the cell level to the inner paragraph level if you still want to keep it - otherwise the border will correspond to the "logical" cell height, i.e. the small one.

Here is the code for the custom cell renderer:

```
class CustomCellRenderer : CellRenderer {
    public CustomCellRenderer(Cell modelElement) : base(modelElement) {
    }

    public override LayoutResult Layout(LayoutContext layoutContext) {
        LayoutResult result = base.Layout(layoutContext);
        result.GetOccupiedArea().GetBBox().SetHeight(0.5f);
        return result;
    }

    public override IRenderer GetNextRenderer() {
        return new CustomCellRenderer((Cell)modelElement);
    }
}
```

And then the complete code:

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("path/to.pdf");
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4, false);
document.SetTopMargin(60f);

Paragraph header = new Paragraph("MEMORANDUM").SetUnderline()
    .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
    .SetFontSize(15);

Paragraph newline = new Paragraph(new Text("\n"));

document.Add(header);
document.Add(newline);
String no = "No.:001/2022";
string perihal = "INTERNAL STACK";

Table table = new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(new
    float[] { 20, 80 })).UseAllAvailableWidth();
table.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);

Cell cell = new Cell(1, 1);
cell.SetPadding(0);
cell.SetNextRenderer(new CustomCellRenderer(cell));
cell.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);

// this is a HEADER CELL
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("<b>Solusi,\nCONTINUED</b>");
p.SetBorder(new SolidBorder(0.5f));
cell.Add(p);
cell.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
table.AddHeaderCell(cell);

cell = new Cell(1, 2);
cell.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
cell.SetItalic().Add(new Paragraph("Continued to Next Page"));
cell.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);

table.AddFooterCell(cell);

table.SetSkipFirstHeader(true);
table.SetSkipLastFooter(true);

string s = @" afsfadsfasfa
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui 
        blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
        voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
        voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
        voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
        voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
        voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
        voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
        voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
        voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
        
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis 
        voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
";
cell = new Cell();
cell.Add(new Paragraph("Solusisssss"));
cell.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
table.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).AddCell(cell);


// this is NON-HEADER CELL    
cell = new Cell();
cell.Add(new Paragraph(s));
cell.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
table.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED).AddCell(cell);

document.Add(table);


int n = pdf.GetNumberOfPages();

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    document.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph(String
            .Format("Page " + i + "/" + n)),
        559, 20, i, TextAlignment.RIGHT,
        VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);

    if (i == 1) continue;
    document.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph(String
            .Format(no)),
        20, 806, i, TextAlignment.LEFT,
        VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);

    document.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph(String
            .Format(perihal)),
        320, 806, i, TextAlignment.CENTER,
        VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);


}

document.Close();
```

Visual result:

[image: result]

Comment: It runs like a charm, thank you very much, Sir, u rock!